Cannot convert value of type 'StandardMultipartFile' to required type 'java.lang.String'
I'm working with Spring Framework, and using some dependencies like Spring Jpa, Spring Web.
I were trying to add a photo in a register using MultipartFile but I got a error result. It returned a problem with the MultipartFile
I had this in my controller:
    @GetMapping("/registrarAdmin")
    public String registrarAdmin(Model model) {
        model.addAttribute("admin", new AdministradorEntity());
        return("registrarAdmin");
    }
    @PostMapping("/registrarAdmin")
    public String registroAdmin(@ModelAttribute("admin")AdministradorEntity adminFormulario,
            Model model, @RequestParam("fotoAdmin") MultipartFile foto) {
        adminService.crearAdmin(adminFormulario, foto);
        return "registrarAdmin";
    }

and the part of the MultipartFile (foto) implements is this:
public static String guardarImagen(MultipartFile foto){
        try {
            Path pathDire = Paths.get("src/main/resources/static/img/guardados/");
            if (!Files.exists(pathDire)) {
                Files.createDirectories(pathDire);
            }
            
            byte[] fotoBytes= foto.getBytes();
            Path pathImagen = Paths.get("src/main/resources/static/img/guardados/" + 
                    foto.getOriginalFilename());
            
                Files.write(pathImagen, fotoBytes);
                return foto.getOriginalFilename();
                
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO: handle exception
            System.out.println("error al cargar la foto"+e.getMessage());
            return null;
        }
}

this is my output:
[2m2024-10-22T09:58:18.785-05:00[0;39m [33m WARN[0;39m [35m15572[0;39m [2m---[0;39m [2m[Proyecto_LP2] [nio-8080-exec-3][0;39m [2m[0;39m[36m.w.s.m.s.DefaultHandlerExceptionResolver[0;39m [2m:[0;39m Resolved [org.springframework.web.bind.MethodArgumentNotValidException: Validation failed for argument [0] in public java.lang.String com.proyecto.controller.AdminController.registroAdmin(com.proyecto.model.AdministradorEntity,org.springframework.ui.Model,org.springframework.web.multipart.MultipartFile): [Field error in object 'admin' on field 'foto': rejected value [org.springframework.web.multipart.support.StandardMultipartHttpServletRequest$StandardMultipartFile@731252d]; codes [typeMismatch.admin.foto,typeMismatch.foto,typeMismatch.java.lang.String,typeMismatch]; arguments [org.springframework.context.support.DefaultMessageSourceResolvable: codes [admin.foto,foto]; arguments []; default message [foto]]; default message [Failed to convert property value of type 'org.springframework.web.multipart.support.StandardMultipartHttpServletRequest$StandardMultipartFile' to required type 'java.lang.String' for property 'foto'; Cannot convert value of type 'org.springframework.web.multipart.support.StandardMultipartHttpServletRequest$StandardMultipartFile' to required type 'java.lang.String' for property 'foto': no matching editors or conversion strategy found]] ]


Finally, this is the implements of the method:
@Override
    public void crearAdmin(AdministradorEntity adminEntity, MultipartFile foto) {
        //Guardando image
        String nombreFoto= Utilitarios.guardarImagen(foto);
        adminEntity.setFoto(nombreFoto);
        //Hash password
        String hashPassword = Utilitarios.hashPassword(adminEntity.getContrasenia());
        adminEntity.setContrasenia(hashPassword);
        
        
        adminRepository.save(adminEntity);
    }

Currently I'm studying this in the institute so I don't know what to do. If you had an idea about the solution or maybe a different way to solve this code, I would like to know. THANKS!!

My pet telepathic slug is escaped its cage, so you have to provide description of error.

Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a minimal reproducible example.

The error occurs because of the foto field in the AdministradorEntity class. Change the name of this field and its corresponding getter and setter to nombreFoto to solve the problem.

thanks Andrey, your answer let me know more about the problem. I fixed it
